# How can I sign a JSON transaction?

Tags: xrp, rippled

I have a JSON representation of an XRPL transaction, like the one below, and I want to sign it in C++ using rippled. How can I?

```
{
  "TransactionType" : "Payment",
  "Account" : "rf1BiGeXwwQoi8Z2ueFYTEXSwuJYfV2Jpn",
  "Destination" : "ra5nK24KXen9AHvsdFTKHSANinZseWnPcX",
  "Amount" : "1000000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse a transaction, represented by the class `STTx` (which stands for "serialized type: transaction"), from JSON. ripple-libpp has good [example code](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-libpp/blob/master/src/test/ripple-libpp_demo.cpp#L39-L51).
2. Construct a signing key, represented by the type [`SecretKey`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/protocol/SecretKey.h). If you have a Base58-encoded signing key, you can use [`parseBase58`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/protocol/SecretKey.h#L117-L120) (pass `TokenType::AccountSecret` for the first parameter).
3. Derive the verifying key (represented by the class `PublicKey`) from the signing key with [`derivePublicKey`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/protocol/SecretKey.h#L138-L140) (pass `KeyType::secp256k1` or `KeyType::ed25519` for the first parameter, depending on the signing algorithm you choose to use).
4. Sign the transaction with [`STTx::sign`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/protocol/impl/STTx.cpp#L166-L179).
5. Read the signature via `Blob const signature = sttx.getFieldVL(sfTxnSignature)` (a [`Blob`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/basics/Blob.h#L30) is a vector of bytes).